# How Do I Extract a PHP JSON Array Name

Tags: php, json, variables, jquery

I have a PHP file that returns a JSON array. I need to extract the array name, in this instance, *Regulatory_Guidance_Library* with jQuery as a var to `$('#navHeaderTitle').text(arrayName);` of my function. I don't know how this is done.

Thnx for your help

My Function in the HTML Doc:

```
function loadNav(url, container, appendE) {
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
                    var arrayName = "";
            $.each(data.Regulatory_Guidance_Library, function(){
                var newItem = $('#' + container).clone();
                // Now fill in the fields with the data
                newItem.find("h1").text(this.label);
                newItem.find("h2").text(this.title);
                newItem.find("p").text(this.description);
                // And add the new list item to the page
                newItem.children().appendTo('#' + appendE)
            });
            $('#navHeaderTitle').text(arrayName);
            //transition(pageName, "show");
        });
    };
```

The served PHP:

```
<?php
//MySQL Database Connect
include 'andaerologin.php';

mysql_select_db("andaero");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from regulatory_list");

$output = new stdClass();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $output->Regulatory_Guidance_Library[] = $row;
}

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo (json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify php:

```
$output = array();
  /* used "key" as name...could change to suit your app*/
$output['key']='Regulatory_Guidance_Library';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $output['items'][]= $row;
}
```

AJAX:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
        $.each(data.items, function(){
            var newItem = $('#' + container).clone();
            // Now fill in the fields with the data
            newItem.find("h1").text(this.label);
            newItem.find("h2").text(this.title);
            newItem.find("p").text(this.description);
            // And add the new list item to the page
            newItem.children().appendTo('#' + appendE)
        });
        $('#navHeaderTitle').text(data.key);
        //transition(pageName, "show");
    });
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Youve been a big help. I'll get this stuff down.  Thnx again

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is probably more helpful, but if you want to get the names of an object's properties with javascript you can do:

```
for (var name in data) {
    alert(name);
}
```

In your case, since you have only one property you could do:

```
for (var name in data) {
    $('#navHeaderTitle').text(name);
}
```